# Force trailing slash in .htaccess doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Without doing anything excepting having some Wordpress sites in subdirectories (not referenced on this website), the links automatically strip the .html endings from themselves. I don't know why this is, but it is the option I want.

Now, I'm having trouble trying to force trailing slash in my site. I tried this option:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

I currently also use this for 404 pages (referencing 404.html):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

But, when trying to access a page, such as http://bluecocoa.com/time/, I got a redirect infinite loop error. I traced the redirects using http://redirectdetective.com. I found that the redirects went like this:

```
http://bluecocoa.com/time --> http://bluecocoa.com/time/ --> http://bluecocoa.com/404 --> http://bluecocoa.com/404/ --> http://bluecocoa.com/404 --> http://bluecocoa.com/404/ --> infinite loop
```

To me, it looks like it fixes the page without the trailing slash by adding one. For some reason, the page with the trailing slash isn't found, and it redirects to 404. The 404 causes an infinite redirect.

My website directory looks like this:

```
index.html
time.html
/mtc/ [a wordpress directory]
/posts/
blog.html
etc...
```

Any help in fixing these issues would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is `/time/` also a directory?

Comment: @JonLin No it's a .html file

Comment: what are you rules that add the .html?

Comment: @JonLin That's another thing that confuses me. I didn't add any rules to remove the ending. For some reason, GoDaddy or maybe an htaccess in a subdirectory with WordPress removes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have these rules to hide `.html` extension in your root `.htaccess`:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect file.html to /file/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=302,NE,L]

# To internally forward /file to /file.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! But there's still an issue. I have my CSS files and images referenced like this: `css/style.css`. When I add your tweak, everything works perfectly, except the images and css and javascript are all broken links. Any thoughts?

Comment: To fix that issue add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's URL.